# How to use c# Dll in vc++?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++

I have created a dll using command line (csc).  Suppose that dll contains Add(int,int) method.  Now I want to use that add function in vc++??

How to do this?

Your Help will be Greatly Appreciated.

Here is what I am doing.

vcproj; for this project i have right click and linker section add additional dependencies.added the path where dll resides.

main.cpp

```
using namespace Test

void main()

{

  demo d;

  d.add(5,5);

}
```

***error namespace Test Does not exist.***

How to resolve this?

I need to use that dll as in unmanaged code

Answer (score 9):

Your C# assembly needs the ComVisible attribute (among a few other things).

```
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
```

There's [a guide to doing this here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736).

Comment: If the C++ application is managed, then it's even easier than this of course, and you can avoid COM altogether.

Comment: @Matthew Brindley i did what is given on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736 but i am getting an error of cannot convert from 'const _GUID' to 'const IISWebFrameworkDAAB::DataAccessInterface'" What should i do?

Answer (score 8):

From MSDN forums [Calling C# from unmanaged C++](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/5345a27a-a614-4a74-9f6d-ea7a999ddf83):

> What you want to do would be to
>   compile only the files where you want
>   to load the C# code /clr and then call
>   away using C++/CLI.  The rest of your
>   app will remain native while those cpp
>   files you compile /clr will be mixed
>   native and CLR.  You should be able to
>   just call into your C# library using
>   C++/CLI syntax.
>
> Once you throw /clr on the cl.exe
>   command line for a file, within that
>   file, you can call any managed code
>   that you want, regardless of whether
>   it was written in VB.net, C# or
>   C++/CLI.  This is by far the easiest
>   way to do what you want to do (call C#
>   code from your native C++ app),
>   although it does have its caveat's and
>   limitations.  By and large though "It
>   Just Works".  Also, it's faster than
>   p/invokes.

Answer (score 2):

This highly depends on what type of C++ application you are building.  If you are building a C++/CLI assembly then you need to make sure the project has a reference to the C# DLL.  Once that is done you should be able to type the code as written assumping you have a definition of Demo like so.

```
namespace Test {
  public class demo {
    public void add(int left, int right) { 
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

If you are building a normal, non-managed, C++ project then you must use COM interop to access the assembly.  This involves making the demo type in your C# project COMVisible and registering it for COM interop.  After which you can access it like any other COM component.

Comment: i followed this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736 all goes well before "Call the Managed DLL from Native C++ Code" but when i try'ed to create a pointer i get the following error "error C2259: 'IISWebFrameworkDAAB::DataAccessInterface' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>          due to following members:
1>          'HRESULT IUnknown::QueryInterface(const IID &,void **)' : is abstract" What should i do?

Comment: Actually the reason for error is "Reason: cannot convert from 'const _GUID' to 'const IISWebFrameworkDAAB::DataAccessInterface'" What should i do?