# Importing C# dll to C++ managed code (.NET)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, c++-cli

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. I've written a dll in C#, managed dll then.
Now for some reason, I need to write a software in C++ (.NET then also managed).
I need to import the C# dll into my C++ .NET code. 
I can't figure out to do this, I've made several search but this problem seems to not be covered. For example, in C# I don't have include file, then how my C++ (.NET) projet knows about classes and functions inside the dll?
Thanks,

Comment: You just need to add only reference of that dll in your project, as George has replied..

Comment: I've already add the dll reference in the c++ project, then what's next?

Comment: then use that namespace or name of classes in your code...

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio, bring up the properties of the C++/CLI project, go to "Common Properties/Framework and References" in the tree at the left, and click the "Add New Reference" button. This will bring up the standard "Add Reference" dialog you can get from a C# project, just select your C# DLL or reference a C# project in the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference into your project. In Visual Studio, right-click your project, then select "References".

Answer (score 0):

You add reference to you assembly, Set `ComVisible attribute` to your assembly

Edit your `AssemblyInfo.cs`

```
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
```

.Net Framework have  MSIL langage in order to manage interoperability betwwen different langages

Link : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add only reference of that dll in your project, as George has replied.
then use that namespace or name of classes in your code...

Answer (score -1):

It is possible. Google search would gave  you answers. Few links from Stackoverflow

[How to use c# Dll in vc++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980808/how-to-use-c-sharp-dll-in-vc)
[using c# dll in project c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799907/using-c-sharp-dll-in-project-c)

and you get many more links https://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=using+c%23+dll+in+vc%2B%2B&oq=using+C%23+dll+&gs_l=hp.3.2.0l4.1601.6409.0.9065.18.13.2.3.3.2.468.2716.0j9j1j2j1.13.0...0.0...1c.1.ixoWIPWicqo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=64f4e49ac7d1c408&biw=936&bih=595

Hope this helps